# how to make ReactCSSTransitionGroup animate elements on setState?

Tags: javascript, animation, reactjs

How to make elements animate on changing state by `setInterval` ?
Trying to render elements in random position and try to animate position changes as following:

```
    var Elem = React.createClass({
        render: function () {
            return (
                <h1 className="elem">
                    Hello, {this.props.name} !
                </h1>
            );
        }
    });


    var MainContainer = React.createClass({
        componentDidMount: function () {
            setInterval(this.shf, 777);
        },
        getInitialState: function () {
            return {source: []};
        },
        shf: function () {
            var source = this.props.source.sort(function () {
                return .5 - Math.random();
            });
            this.setState({
                source: source
            });
        },

        render: function () {
            var ReactCSSTransitionGroup = React.addons.CSSTransitionGroup;
            var Elems = this.state.source.map(function (elem, i) {
                return (
                    <ReactCSSTransitionGroup key={i * 10}
                                             transitionName="example"
                                             transitionAppear={true} transitionAppearTimeout={500}
                                             transitionEnter={true} transitionLeave={true}>
                        <Elem key={i} number={i} name={elem}/>
                    </ReactCSSTransitionGroup>
                );
            }, this);
            return (
                <div>
                    {Elems}
                </div>
            );
        }
    });
    ReactDOM.render(<MainContainer source={["bill", "bob", "sam", "john", "smith"]}/>,
        document.getElementById('container'));
```

CodePen link with styles : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZOQmJX

It is animating on rendering the first time but, not on the every State changes, how to achieve it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
componentDidMount: function () {
   setInterval(this.shf, 777);
}
```

=>

```
componentDidMount: function () {
   setInterval(()=>this.shf(), 777);
}
```

When setState is called,this.state.source has changed,but the children of ReactCSSTransitionGroup node has no change,five node with same key and same sequence.

```
render: function () {
        var ReactCSSTransitionGroup = React.addons.CSSTransitionGroup;
        var Elems = this.state.source.map(function (elem, i) {
            return (
                    <Elem key={elem} number={i} name={elem}/>
            );
        }, this);
        return (
            <ReactCSSTransitionGroup
                                         transitionName="example"
                                         transitionAppear={true} transitionAppearTimeout={500}
                                         transitionEnter={true} transitionLeave={true}>
                {Elems}
            </ReactCSSTransitionGroup>
        );
    }
```

or only change

```
<Elem key={elem} number={i} name={elem}/>
```

Comment: thanks, but this did not make the elements animate on re-rendering via `this.shf()`